# How to include fields in email message

Tags: php, email

I have the following code for sending mail:

```
$email_to = 'someone@somewhere.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email_to . '>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'sent'; // sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the mail is sent..      
} else {
    echo 'failed'; // ... or this one to tell it that it wasn't sent    
}
```

The mail sends fine but I need to display the phone number along with the message.  I'm sure it's an easy fix and I'll be all "doh!" when someone schools me, so let's get it over with! :)

Comment: This code is attackable via SMTP Injection: https://www.hellboundhackers.org/articles/867-smtp-injection.html

Comment: Not understanding why the -3 votes.  It's a 101 question, but valid none-the-less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the phone number to the message string.

```
$email_to = 'someone@somewhere.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];  
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'] . "\n\n" . $phone;

$headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email_to . '>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'sent'; // sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the mail is sent..      
} else {
    echo 'failed'; // ... or this one to tell it that it wasn't sent    
}
```

Comment: See! SOOOO obvious!  Anyone got a 'think about something for a minute before asking for help!' book laying around?  Thanks, Dean.

Comment: Be sure to "accept" this answer and see the other comment about SMTP injection.

Answer (score 0):

Put the phone number in the `$message` variable. Something like

```
$message = $_POST['message']."<br/><br/>Your phone number is: ".$phone;
```

Also add the proper headers to support HTML:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the phone number to the message in order for it to be sent.

```
$message = $_POST['message']."\n\n$phone";
```

You should also look up functions for preventing email injection, and also run strip_tags on every post value to prevent XSS attacks on your form.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but just letting you know it should be `$message = $_POST['message']."\n\n".$phone;`

Comment: You can place variables in double quotes, and since you have to use double quotes to use \n anyway, why not?